# mysql how to keep key for aes_encrypt

Tags: mysql, security

I have a question on where to store the key for aes_encrypt. See below, you can see I store the key into one separate table. My question is: can I keep the key on OS level ? Let say in one txt file and each time from MySQL somehow read the key from that file using "SQL statement" ?

```
drop table if exists lr_words;

create table lr_words
(
    word varchar(300)
);

insert into lr_words(word) values ('my_key');

drop function if exists lr_encrypt;
delimiter $$
create function lr_encrypt(p_text varchar(1000) character set UTF8)
   returns varbinary(200)
begin

    declare l_word varchar(300) default '';
    declare l_key_length int default 512;

    select word
      into l_word  
      from lr_words;

    return aes_encrypt(p_text, SHA2(l_word,l_key_length));

end
$$

drop function if exists lr_decrypt;
delimiter $$
create function lr_decrypt(p_text varbinary(200))
   returns text character set UTF8
begin

    declare l_word varchar(300) default '';
    declare l_key_length int default 512;

    select word
      into l_word  
      from lr_words;

    return cast(aes_decrypt(p_text, SHA2(l_word,l_key_length)) AS char(1000));

end
$$

select lr_encrypt(email) as email_en, 
lr_decrypt(lr_encrypt(email)) as email_dec
from my_table
```

All this work fine, but I want to keep the key outside the database !

Comment: can't, really. mysql can't access external files, other than via `load data infile`, which means the key would be in a table, even if only for a short time. and if the mysql server can access the file, then ANYTHING using mysql can access the file as well. you'd have gained nothing in the way of security.

Comment: What is communicating with your database?  A web application?

Comment: no application - it's just database used for analytics